# Reorderable favorite tags - drag & drop ordering for the Watched tag sidebar

Tags: script, favorite

### Screenshot

[image: action shot of a tag being dragged to reorder it on the Watched Tags sidebar]

### About

Motivated by this question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368024/have-favorite-tags-always-been-alphabetized/

> This'll restore the previous behavior: tags will remain in the order in which you add them.
>
> But it'll even do one better: per rene's suggestion from the comments, it'll also allow you to reorder the tags at will by dragging them around (you have to start editing them first though, so as to avoid inadvertently reordering them while trying to click).

#### License

[CC-BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) of course

#### Download

View the source here: https://github.com/Shog9/ReoderableFavorateTags/blob/master/reorderablefavoritetags.user.js

Get Tampermonkey or whatever you use to run userscripts, then install here: https://github.com/Shog9/ReoderableFavorateTags/raw/master/reorderablefavoritetags.user.js

#### Platform

Tested on Chrome 68 and Firefox 61

Works in Tampermonkey; probably works in Greasemonkey but untested.

### Contact

Feel free to make useful changes & submit a pull request on GitHub.

Comment: I dunno; [that `@description`](https://github.com/Shog9/ReoderableFavorateTags/blob/master/reorderablefavoritetags.user.js#L3) sounds dicey...

Comment: Look, my setup works for me.

Comment: Is "Chrome 6.8" supposed to mean Chrome 68, or did you actually try it in Chrome 6.8?

Comment: Definitely supposed to be 68, @astonearachnid